# javascript floating menu bar in holding div

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript menu bar that is positioned on my webpage, then when the browser bar reaches the top of the menu it locks into a fixed position and moves with the window. However, i need to contain the menu within a div, how can this be done?

This is my menu bar:

```
<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 200)
        {
            $("#floatbar").css({position:'fixed',left:'0',top:'0'});
        }
        else
        {
            $("#floatbar").css({position:'absolute',left:'0',top:'200px'});
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

and this is my html:

```
<div id="menu_runner">
    <div id="floatbar">
        <a href="#issue49">Issue 49</a><br />
        <a href="#issue48">Issue 48</a><br />
        <a href="#issue47">Issue 47</a><br />
        <a href="#issue46">Issue 46</a><br />
    </div>
</div>
```

and my css:

```
#menu_runner {
    width: 100px;
    height: 2000px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
#floatbar {
    width: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
}
```

where the menu runner is the containing div of the menu, and the floatbar obviously contains the menu which runs the JavaScript.

However when I try this code, the menu sticks to the left and 200px from the top, and not within the menu_runner div. How can i make the floatbar be positioned in the menu_runner div and then scroll down with the JavaScript within the div as it should.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need it to be wrapped in a div? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The menu will be placed on the right hand side of a two column layout, the left hand column holds text and the right hand colum will be the menu bar which moves down the page as the viewer looks through the data, so they can quickly jump from one place on the page to another (the menu simply links to ID's on the page).

I cant use absolute positioning to achieve this as obviously as screen size differs the menu bar would be in different places. I could use AP to position the menu from the top of the screen ok, but the positioning no the horizontal axis would be wrong in any other size screen.

Comment: Not sure if this will be helpful, as it doesn't fix your own code, but http://www.jtricks.com/javascript/navigation/floating.html seems to be a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

`if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 0)`  <------set it to zero or
you could use css

```
#floatbar {
     position:fixed;
     top: 10px;  /* tells browser the div should position at the very bottom of the window */
     right: 1px;  /* tells the browser the div should have no space on the right */
     left: 1px;  /* tells the browser the div should have no space on the left */
     margin: 1px; /* because we want this width: 100%, the margin must be 0 */
     padding: 1px; /* because we want the width: 100%, the padding must be 0 */
     width: 10px; /* makes the div a bar stretching across the bottom of the screen */
     height: 35px; /* makes the floating bar 35 pixels high*/
     z-index: 9999; /*positions this div on top of all other elements in the site - this number can increase or decrease to your liking */
     border:1px solid #000;
}
```